# get UTC timestamp from today's local time

Tags: javascript, timestamp, unix-timestamp, utc

Let's assume I know this time (hh:mm:ss) without date but I know it is today:

> 12:34:56

And I know the time is in CST timezone (UTC +0800). I need to get timestamp from the time.

Let's assume current **UTC time is 2014/08/25 17:10:00** and **CST is 2014/08/26 01:10:00** (UTC +0800) so it means in CST is already the next day. Therefore I can't use something like this:

```
var d = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10);
// "d" returns "2014-08-25" in local time -> this is bad
```

**I need to convert this:**

> **1:10** (CST) --> to **2014/08/25 17:10** (UTC) or its timestamp **1408986600**

**How can I get full date-time or timestamp when I know the time and timezone only?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the easy way using [moment-timezone.js](http://momentjs.com/timezone/):

```
// hh:mm:ss in CST timezone
var cst_time = '1:10:00'; 

// get today's date in CST timezone
var cst_today = moment.tz("Asia/Shanghai").format("YYYY-MM-DD"); 

// convert date and time from CST to UTC and format it
var timestamp = moment(cst_today + " " + cst_time + " +0800").utc().format("YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss");

// returns "2014/08/25 17:10:00" and it is correct
console.log(timestamp);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always manipulate the properties of a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object directly:

```
var date = new Date();

date.setHours(5);
date.setMinutes(12);
date.setSeconds(10);

console.log(date.toUTCString());
```

Comment: How to "say" the Date object it is in CST and not local time? I am not in CST but the time above "1:10" is.

Comment: Does `new Date` produce a date in the correct time zone for you? Within NodeJS it uses your time-zone environment variable. In the browser it should use your operating system setting. I don't know there's any easy way to set to a non-local timezone, but the libraries available differ between NodeJS and in the browser world. Alternatively you can always shift the UTC timestamp value by an appropriate number of seconds and re-render.